# Is web.py Python 3 compatible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web.py

Is web.py Python 3 compatible?

Comment: You can try bottle (a python web frame which is very similar with webby).  bottle has python 3 versions. http://bottle.paws.de

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSGI is not yet Python 3 compatible (see http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/SupportForPython3X ) and hence webpy is not.

Comment: As of April, 2011, this is no longer true.

Comment: @pjz can you explain? I cannot find anything about web.py working with Python3. Trying to do the install using 3 doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I believe pjz was saying that WSGI is Python 3 compatible, not web.py.  It is possible to update wsgiserver from the CherryPy repository and make some changes to web.py to get it to run in Python 3, but at present web.py is not P3-ready.

See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/webpy/Qa-U1kABk4w/WeOvy-V51sgJ for more.